# Do Old Indian words with voiceless aspirated stops have cognates in other branches of Indogermanic?

Tags: historical-linguistics, indo-european, sanskrit, stops, indo-aryan

Inspired by [this answer](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/31376/9781) I have this question: Do Old Indic (Vedic, Sankrit) words beginning with a voiceless aspirated stop (like ph, th, or kh) have cognates in other branches of Indogermanic? What are typical regular sound correspondences?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-European_sound_laws) lists Sanskrit ph, th, kh as the regular correspondences for PIE *p, *t, *k before an original laryngeal

Comment: Well, yes, but that's circular. Laryngeals are posited in the first place because of their effect on surrounding sounds.

Comment: @jlawler It's not circular if there's independent evidence for the laryngeals in question, as in some cases there is.

Answer (score 3):

As a rule, the voiceless aspirates are a dialectal feature. In most languages, they cannot be distinguished from plain voiceless.
As regards *kh, the typical pattern is Old Indian kh, Armenian x, Greek k(h). For example, in a potentially onomatopeic verb: *kakh- "to laugh", where probably no laryngeal is involved.
As regards *th, typically Old Indian th, Armenian t, Greek t(h), very often preceded by initial s- as in *st(h)eH- "to stand", cf. *pont(H)- "path, way through", *ost(H)- "bone".
As regards *ph, typically Old Indian ph, Armenian ph, Greek p(h), a good example is *(s-)phol- "to fall".

Comment: Wikipedia (for what it's worth) agrees with you on /kh/, and lists Skt खादति khā́dati :: OArm խածանեմ xacane, from PIE kʷh₂ed-.

Comment: What do you mean by "*dialectal feature*"? Does this indicate an irregular and sporadic correspondence, or can it be consistently traced to certain dialects?

Comment: It seems that the creation of a fourth series of consonants: the voiceless aspirated series, occurred only in a subset of probably contiguous languages: Greek, Armenian and Indo-Iranian. In the other languages, the phonotaxis of C+H did not create an additional series: voiceless C+H=C. The verb *kakh- "to laugh" has a variant in Germanic *hlah- < *klakh-, so Germanic is somehow close to this subset of "Central Indo-European" languages. So this isogloss is dialectal in the sense that only a few languages are involved.